# How to dynamicly add listeners to an arraylist of JLabels that call a method

Tags: java, arraylist, mouseevent, actionlistener, jlabel

I have a grid of `JLabel`s. I added them all to an ArrayList. How do I add `MouseClickListener`s to all of them through iteration.
Something alone the lines of:

```
    for (int i=0;i<145;i++)
    jLAL.get(i).addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jLabelMouseClicked(evt, jLAL.get(i));
        }
    });
```

jLAL is the jLabel `ArrayList`. The bad thing here of course is that it can't be final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If BlackBox solution can't be implemented in your code, just create a method that will add the listener where the `JLabel` will be final.

```
    for (int i=0;i<145;i++) {
      addListener(jLAL.get(i));
    }
  }

  private void addListener(final JLabel jLabel) {
    jLabel.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
      public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        jLabelMouseClicked(evt, jLabel);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for (int i=0;i<jLAL.size();i++)
final int temp = i;
jLAL.get(i).addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        jLabelMouseClicked(evt, jLAL.get(temp ));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop through the size of the `ArrayList` and add each one, but I'd recommend making a custom ADD method which does it for you as it avoids later looping.

```
public void addLabel(JLabel label){
    label.addMouseListener(yourlistener);
    arraylist.add(label);
}
```

so instead of calling `arraylist.add()` for each JLabel you want to add, you add with `addLabel()`.